# Python Pandas handling of 308 request

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-science

When trying to read England's Covid_19 data into pandas, I've tried to use the URL provided by PHE `https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/downloads/csv/coronavirus-cases_latest.csv` however, this file needs a http 308 redirect. I have tried the elegant solution:

```
import pandas as pd
tabel = pd.read_csv('https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/downloads/csv/coronavirus-cases_latest.csv')
```

which trows the error `HTTPError: HTTP Error 308: Permanent Redirect`

However, the URL works as

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import io
datastr = requests.get('https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/downloads/csv/coronavirus-cases_latest.csv',allow_redirects=True).text
data_file = io.StringIO(datastr)
table = pd.read_csv(data_file)
```

gives the desired result.

I would like something similar to the first solution, is this a problem of pandas or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Pandas source, it uses urllib.request.urlopen() and the docs suggest it should follow redirects where it makes sense.

However, 308 isn't a defined redirect code according to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231, so urllib will throw an exception as it doesn't know what to do. The requests library is a bit more forgiving.

The response says "permanent redirect", but looking at the dodgy hosting, I doubt that's really what is meant.

I think the publisher has messed up, so I wouldn't spend much time with other than the workaround you have.

Note that requests does let you get at the raw stream which you can pass to pd.read_csv():

```
r = requests.get('https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/downloads/csv/coronavirus-cases_latest.csv', stream=True)
pd.read_csv(r.raw)
```

Comment: 308 is defined by [RDF 7538: The Hypertext Transfer Protocol Status Code 308 (Permanent Redirect)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7538) however.

Comment: Also, see this: [bugs.python.org/issue40321: urllib.request does not support HTTP response status code 308](https://bugs.python.org/issue40321)